# My If Else statement is not working to provide maximum value in a vector (C++)

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to return the max. value in a vector in C++, but I am constantly getting only the last value as the response (I am guessing it is because the if-else loop is somehow not doing the comparison and is just assigning the next value to "maxVal"). For example, the below code is returning 30 as the answer. What am I doing wrong? Can you please help?

Below is the code ->

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

double max (const vector<double>& myVector)   {
int n = myVector.size();
double maxVal;
for (int i=0; i<=n-1; i++) {
    if (maxVal <= myVector[i+1])  {
        maxVal = myVector[i+1];   
    }
    else {
        maxVal = myVector[i];
    }

}
return maxVal; 
}

int main() {
vector<double> testVector;
testVector.push_back(10.0);
testVector.push_back(200.0);
testVector.push_back(30.0);
cout << max(testVector);
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Usually `i <= n-1` would be written `i < n`. This would actually be important if `n` was an unsigned integer like `std::size_t`.

Comment: On every iteration, you are setting the value of `maxVal` to either the current element or the next element. Thus, you are calculating the max **of the last two** vector elements.

Comment: Beware that `i+1` will be beyond the bounds of your vector on the last iteration.

Comment: maxVal  not initialized in function max (). Use double maxVal = myVector[0];

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is the wrong way to handle such a situation: I advise you to put debugging lines (`cout` or whatever), and show the progress of your values MaxVal, i, MyVector[i+1], ..., and see how they evolve. Like this you'll learn what's wrong and how to handle this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ has a rich library and I don't understand why people don't use it.
Here is a two line version that finds the maximum value of a vector. Please, don't reinvent the wheel.

```
#include <iostream>                                                                                                                                                                                                
#include <vector>                                                                                                                                                                                                  
#include <algorithm>                                                                                                                                                                                                

int main()                                                                                                                                                                                                         
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  auto v = std::vector{4, 3, 2, 1};                                                                                                                                                                               
  std::cout << *max_element(v.cbegin(), v.cend()) << "\n";                                                                                                                                                         
}
```

Answer (score 2):

*(I assume that the vector is not empty)*

This work:

```
double max(const std::vector<double>& myVector)
{
    size_t n = myVector.size();
    double maxVal = myVector[0];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (myVector[i] > maxVal)
            maxVal = myVector[i];
    }

    return maxVal;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> testVector{ 10.0 , 200.0 , 30.0 };

    std::cout << max(testVector);

    return 0;
}
```

Keep it simple & readable: Initialize the maxVal with the 1st element of the vector, Run on all elements, & if one is bigger than maxVal, update maxVal.

Answer (score 0):

Make things easy on yourself, use the standard algorithms.

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
for (int i=0; i<=n-1; i++) {
    if (maxVal <= myVector[i+1])  {
        maxVal = myVector[i+1];   
    }
    else {
        maxVal = myVector[i];
    }
}
```

you change the value of `maxVal` on every iteration. In the end `maxVal` can only be either the value of the last element or an elements one past your array. Which brings me to the next problem: Valid indicees are 0 up to (including) n-1, so when you are at `i==n-1` then `i+1` is out of your array.

Actaully there is no need to consider the next or previous element so change it to

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {        // loop from 0 till n-1 
    if (maxVal < myVector[i]) {  // no need to check equality
        maxVal = myVector[i];   
    }                            // no need for else
}                                // if maxVal is bigger then it 
                                 // is already the max so far
```